# PHP 5.5: "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of" at session_start()

Tags: php, session, memory-leaks, php-5.5

For testing purpose, my local environment has just one user connected, so there is one php session saved in /var/lib/php/session.

The memory limit configured for php processes is the default 128Mb.

The script loads rows from database and saves it on $_SESSION using arrays; the session's file size (sess_xxxxxxxx) then is 16Mb.

When refreshing page (ctrl-r), why I'm getting "Allowed memory size of" error at session_start() if -obviously to me- session file is a lot smaller than memory limit?

```
echo memory_get_usage(true)/1048576; //this shows 3.5 (Mb) always
session_start(); //first time ok, fails on refreshing page
```

I know I have to refactor the sql query, but to understand what's happening:

-php deserialize the file session increasing its size in some way?

-session_start() internally creates copies of session's files data so it's exceeding the memory limit?

Any thoughts I will appreciate.